# sending text file as email with curl when text file has variable

Tags: bash, curl, global-variables

I have a script that sends an email with curl. For example:

`name="John"
curl...`

I have a text file for my email template. The template will have the `$name` variable in it. For example:

`Hello, $name. This is a test.`

The curl part is fine but the problem is that it sends `Hello, $name. This is a test` instead of `Hello, John. This is a test`. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried to search how to do it but I'm not even sure how to phrase the question. I keep turning up stuff on reading variables values from a files which isn't what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Can you show us the command that is producing the wrong result?

Comment: `curl --netrc-file "/config/.netrc" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "<myemail@gmail.com>" --mail-rcpt "<youremail@gmail.com>" --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -T /config/test.txt`

It shouldn't have anything to do with the command should it? I thought it was more of an issue with the shell.

Comment: Where are you using the `name` variable here?

Comment: As I mentioned, in the text file.

Comment: So you have a variable in the file and you want to use the variable's value in  the `curl` command you are using subsequently?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/config/test.txt`? you have the variable stored here?

Comment: I already did in the original post.

Comment: Maybe using `eval` somehow? I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue:

`eval message=$(cat test.txt) | echo $message| curl --netrc-file "/config/.netrc" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "<myemail@gmail.com>" --mail-rcpt "<youremail@gmail.com>" --url smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -T -`